# iOS app - changing the orientation in tabbar

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller

In my app I have a tabbar with 5 buttons. The total app has only portrait orientation and I have set it correctly.

My problem is that when I click the second button of the tabbar, the view appears normally in portrait but when the user tilts the device I want that particular view to be get changed to landscape. Is it possible to change the tabbar position to landscape and when the other buttons are clicked all to be changed to portrait?

Else while it is tilted I have to show the view alone in landscape without the tabbar, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

So, to be clear, you want the entire app and all views in portrait EXCEPT for the view triggered by the second tab bar button, which you want to always appear in Landscape?

if I've not confused your question, than just put the following line of code in the "viewDidLoad" method of the controller of view number 2

```
self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to bite the bullet and let your project accept multiple orientations at its highest level and then decide per UIViewController which orientations are supported. This will allow the frameworks to take care of a lot of the work for you (always a good idea).

In each view's controller, override this method:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

You will want to return `YES` for any orientation that you want the view to support.

The four options for the interfaceOrientation parameter are:

```
UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait
UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown
UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft
UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight
```

So for your case, you will want the view controller hosting your view and tab bar to support all of the orientations. This is how the function would look:

```
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations.
    return YES;
}
```

But for a extra detail, if you wanted to support only Landscape Left and Portrait Upside Down orientation, the function would look like this:

```
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations.
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A UITabBar only supports rotation, if the ViewControllers of all tabs return YES at shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation.

You could achieve what you want, if you let your "portrait" tabs check if they are visible (via

```
tabbar.selectedViewController
```

or
    tabbar.selectedIndex

and only reply yes when they're not selected.

The user experience could be confusing though, when the user changes the tab in landscape mode
a portrait view is presented ...

Answer (score 0):

try this w.r.t.: `tabbar.selectedViewController`

`[[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight];`